# angular-slider want to slide from 0 to 100 in UI but in the backhand from 200 to 5000

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uislider

I have created an slider application in angularjs using angular-slider, I have set the floor to 200 and ceiling 5000 and step as 1. The application is working fine but the issue is that I want to show the slider to run from 0 to 100 in the ui but behind the scene it should be from 200 to 5000.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MHvH7D4pppA5a1MsgPiN?p=preview)**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
    <div style="width: 880px;">
        200 <slider style="width:400px;" floor="200" ceiling="1000" step="1" ng-model="speedSlider"></slider>{{speedSlider}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

Can anyone have some suggestion for this

Comment: `backendValue = 200 + 4800 * uiValue/100` ?

Comment: @Yoshi I am not getting, In the above equation if uiValue is 1 then backendValue will be 50, if uiValue 100 then backendValue will be 5000

Comment: What I mean is, that you can do all sorts of fancy stuff to transform those values. But the simplest would be to have the slider go from 0-100 and use that value as a factor to calculate the *backend value*.

Comment: @Yoshi yeah that's a good catch

Comment: Here's a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/xetulugulu/1/